# Bitwise Logic Murder

Tags: cipher

Murderer out on the street!!

He is somewhere, but you now need to find him.

He has left 3 images on a computer, all of them are 16px by 16px blocks of colors

You remove the junk (all the # and the spaces) and get:

95a47a7893879cd56dd921f44926d9f8dd65beefe5d39eb55c44aaca8faf5c329549c09928fbf7e8

89a478788493d8f238976ba31f61cd888034fda6a4ecd19a5549bbdd8eb81232f10587c065afa1b8

c5c50c11f0e6bc9702b74695274ff9b9b301cc8a84a0bef43220cfa8eadd2812c43ca9f75c9a9989

Hint 1:

> ASCII is used at some point, but I wol't tell you when

Hint 2: (don't look at this if you want to try to figure it out)

> The title has an important clue.

Bonus:

> There is a SECOND key that you can use, but can you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Latitude: -68.41351, Longitude: 59.79581

which is

> Antarctica.

Which you get by

> xor with the second and last string interpreted as hex.

You also get

> Pavica Bongani Andreas Andebert Quintana

but I guess we already have a location, so this might be irrelevant information.

Comment: Correct. You have found the method I used!

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^{2^3}=256$ boolean functions on three variables.  If we look at all of them (applied to the bits of the inputs interpreted as decimal and converted to ASCII), we get the following (each line is a separate function, and non-printing characters are represented by `.`):

```
".......................................   ~(x|y|z)
@A..`` .. .. . ."..... @" D `@ ..0(&....   ~x&~y&z
b[..hh#.. ...."."..... @..D p@....8&....   ~(x|y)
......@ ..............A......... .......   ~x&y&~z
*.....C(..............A.........*.......   ~(x|z)
HA..dp` . ..0.$.".....aJ#)T5`@". 0.&....   y^z^(x&y)^(x&z)
j[..lxc(. ....&.".....aJ..T5p@..*.>&....   ~x&~(y&z)
..........B..A....@.. ..........@..@D...   ~x&y&z
".................@.. ..........J..@....   ~x&(~y|z)&(y|~z)
@A..`` ..&F.&I .".@..  @" E `P .@4)fT...   ~x&z
b[..hh#..&....".".@..  @..E pP..J.9f....   ~x&(~y|z)
......@"..J..A....A..,A.........`..@E...   ~x&y
*.....C*..........A..,A.........j..@....   ~x&(y|~z)
HA..dp`".&N.6I$.".A..,aJ#)U5`P".`4/fU...   ~x&(y|z)
j[..lxc*.&....&.".A..,aJ..U5pP..j.?f....   ~x
........EH.@@..@L@.AA.........D..@@..@F@   x&~y&~z
2........H.H...FL..Q[.............P..@FF   ~(y|z)
PA..c` .Gh.@`. An@.AA. A*$D"aBd..ph..@NA   x^z^(x&y)^(y&z)
r[..kh#..h.H.."Gn..Q[. A..D"qB....x..@NG   ~(x&z)&~y
......@ UH.BP..@LP.AA.A.......F. @F..DFP   x^y^(x&z)^(y&z)
:.....C(.H.J...FL..Q[.A.........*.V..DFV   ~(x&y)&~z
XA..gp` Wh.Bp.$AnP.AA.aK+-T7aBf. pn..DNQ   x^y^z^(x&y&z)
z[..oxc(.h.J..&Gn..Q[.aK..T7qB..*.~..DNW   ~((x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z))
........ENBAFA.@L@BAA3........D.@DAHD@F@   x^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z)
2........N.I...FL.BQ[3..........J.QH.@FF   ~(y^z^(x&y&z))
PA..c` .GnFAfI An@BAA3 A*$E"aRd.@tinT@NA   x^z^(x&y)^(x&y&z)
r[..kh#..n.I.."Gn.BQ[3 A..E"qR..J.yn.@NG   ~(y^(x&z)^(y&z))
......@"UNJCVA.@LPCAA?A.......F.`DGHEDFP   x^y^(x&z)^(x&y&z)
:.....C*.N.K...FL.CQ[?A.........j.WH.DFV   ~(z^(x&y)^(y&z))
XA..gp`"WnNCvI$AnPCAA?aK+-U7aRf.`tonUDNQ   x^y^z^(y&z)
z[..oxc*.n.K..&Gn.CQ[?aK..U7qR..j..n.DNW   ~x|~(y|z)
...............0.......$................   x&~y&z
&..............6.......$................   (~x|z)&(x|~z)&~y
DA..pd$.. .. .013......d" D `E(..8(7....   ~y&z
f[..xl'.. ....273......d..D pE....87....   (~x|z)&~y
......D%.......0......O.........$.......   y^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z)
......G-.......6......O.................   ~(x^z^(x&y&z))
LA..ttd%. ..0.413.....on#)T5`E*.$8.7....   y^z^(x&y)^(x&y&z)
n[..||g-. ....673.....on..T5pE....>7....   ~(x^(x&z)^(y&z))
..........B..G.0..@.. .$........D..QL...   (x&z)^(y&z)
&..............6..@.. .$........N..Q....   ~(x^y^z^(x&y)^(x&y&z))
DA..pd$..&F.&O013.@.. .d" E `U(.D<)w\...   z^(x&y&z)
f[..xl'..&....273.@.. .d..E pU..N.9w....   ~(x^y^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z))
......D'..J..G.0..A..,O.........d..QM...   (x&~y&z)|(~x&y)
......G/.......6..A..,O.........n..Q....   ~(x^z^(y&z))
LA..ttd'.&N.6O413.A..,on#)U5`U*.d</w]...   (~x&y)|(~y&z)
n[..||g/.&....673.A..,on..U5pU..n.?w....   ~x|(~y&z)
........EH.T@..p]A.IA..%......L..H@..PV@   x&~y
6........H.\...v]..Y[..%..........P..PVF   (x|~z)&~y
TA..sd$.Gh.T`.0q.A.IA..e*$D"aGl..xh?.P^A   (x|z)&~y
v[..{l'..h.\..2w...Y[..e..D"qG....x?.P^G   ~y
......D%UH.VP..p]Q.IA.O/......N.$HF..TVP   x^y^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
>.....G-.H.^...v]..Y[.O/..........V..TVV   ~(z^(x&y)^(x&z))
\A..wtd%Wh.Vp.4q.Q.IA.oo+-T7aGn.$xn?.T^Q   x^y^z^(x&z)
~[...|g-.h.^..6w...Y[.oo..T7qG....~?.T^W   ~(x|z)|~y
........ENBUFG.p]ABIA3.%......L.DLAYLPV@   (x&~y)|(~x&y&z)
6........N.]...v].BY[3.%........N.QY.PVF   ~(y^z^(x&z))
TA..sd$.GnFUfO0q.ABIA3.e*$E"aWl.D|i.\P^A   (x&~y)|(~x&z)
v[..{l'..n.]..2w..BY[3.e..E"qW..N.y..P^G   (~x&z)|~y
......D'UNJWVG.p]QCIA?O/......N.dLGYMTVP   x^y
>.....G/.N._...v].CY[?O/........n.WY.TVV   (~x|~y)&(x|y|~z)
\A..wtd'WnNWvO4q.QCIA?oo+-U7aWn.d|o.]T^Q   (~x|~y)&(x|y|z)
~[...|g/.n._..6w..CY[?oo..U7qW..n....T^W   ~(x&y)
. ph...@(.! . ...$0$ @..D@ @. . .... !     x&y&~z
":.....H...(......04:@.... @. .......! &   (~x|y)&(x|~y)&~z
@ati`a @* % (( ."$0$ @ @f`d`d`0 .1(&0!(!   z^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z)
b{..hi#H. .(..".".04:@ @..d`t`....8&.!('   ~(x^y^(x&y&z))
. ph..@`8.)". ...41$ LA.EI0U. . 1...!% 0   y&~z
*:....Ch...*......14:LA...0U. ..;....% 6   (~x|y)&~z
Hatidq``: -"8($."41$ LaJgitud`2 11.&1%(1   y^z^(x&z)^(x&y&z)
j{..lych. .*..&.".14:LaJ..tut`..;.>&.%(7   ~(x^(x&y)^(y&z))
. ph...B(.c!.a...$p$ `..D@!@.0. Q..@d!     (x&y)^(y&z)
":.....J...)......p4:`....!@.0..[..@.! &   ~(x^y^z^(x&z)^(x&y&z))
@ati`a B*&g!.i ."$p$ ` @f`e`dp0 Q5)ft!(!   (x&y&~z)|(~x&z)
b{..hi#J.&.)..".".p4:` @..e`tp..[.9f.!('   ~(x^y^(y&z))
. ph..@b8.k#.a...4q$ lA.EI1U.0. q..@e% 0   y^(x&y&z)
*:....Cj...+......q4:lA...1U.0..{..@.% 6   ~(x^z^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z))
Hatidq`b:&o#>i$."4q$ laJgiuudp2 q5/fu%(1   y^z^(x&z)^(y&z)
j{..lycj.&.+..&.".q4:laJ..uutp..{.?f.%(7   ~x|(y&~z)
. rh...@mH!`H .@Ld2eaS..LD B."T .A@. af`   x&~z
2:.....H.H.h...FL.2u{S.... B."....P..aff   (x|~y)&~z
Pavica @oh%`h( And2eaS Anddbebt .qh.0ana   x^z^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
r{..ki#H.h.h.."Gn.2u{S A..dbub....x..ang   ~(y^(x&y)^(x&z))
. rh..@`}H)bX .@Lt3ea_A.MM0W."V 1AF.!efp   (x|y)&~z
::....Ch.H.j...FL.3u{_A...0W."..;.V..efv   ~z
Xavigq``.h-bx($Ant3ea_aKomtwebv 1qn.1enq   x^y^z^(x&y)
z{..oych.h.j..&Gn.3u{_aK..twub..;.~..enw   ~(x|y)|~z
. rh...BmNcaNa.@Ldreas..LD!B.2T QEAHdaf`   (x&~z)|(~x&y&z)
2:.....J.N.i...FL.ru{s....!B.2..[.QH.aff   ~(y^z^(x&y))
Pavica Bongani Andreas Andebert Quintana   x^z
r{..ki#J.n.i.."Gn.ru{s A..ebur..[.yn.ang   (~x|~z)&(x|~y|z)
. rh..@b}Nkc^a.@Ltsea.A.MM1W.2V qEGHeefp   (x&~z)|(~x&y)
::....Cj.N.k...FL.su{.A...1W.2..{.WH.efv   (~x&y)|~z
Xavigq`b.noc~i$Antsea.aKomuwerv quonuenq   (~x|~z)&(x|y|z)
z{..oycj.n.k..&Gn.su{.aK..uwur..{..n.enw   ~(x&z)
. ph...E(.!4.&.0.%0, @.$D@ @.%. ....(10    (x&y)^(x&z)
&:.....M...<...6..0<:@.$.. @.%.......10&   ~(x^y^z^(y&z)^(x&y&z))
Datipe$E* %4(.013%0, @.df`d`de8 .9(7818!   (x&y&~z)|(~y&z)
f{..xm'M. .<..273.0<:@.d..d`te....87.18'   ~(x^y^(x&z))
. ph..De8.)6.&.0.51, LO.EI0U.%. 5...)500   (x&~y&z)|(y&~z)
.:....Gm...>...6..1<:LO...0U.%..?....506   ~(x^z^(x&y))
Latitude: -68.41351, Longitude: 59.79581   y^z
n{..|}gm. .>..673.1<:Lon..tute..?.>7.587   (~x|y|z)&(~y|~z)
. ph...G(.c5.g.0.%p, `.$D@!@.5. U..Ql10    (x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
&:.....O...=...6..p<:`.$..!@.5.._..Q.10&   ~(x^y^z)
Datipe$G*&g5.o013%p, `.df`e`du8 U=)w|18!   z^(x&y)
f{..xm'O.&.=..273.p<:`.d..e`tu.._.9w.18'   ~(x^y^(x&z)^(y&z)^(x&y&z))
. ph..Dg8.k7.g.0.5q, lO.EI1U.5. u..Qm500   y^(x&z)
.:....Go...?...6..q<:lO...1U.5.....Q.506   ~(x^z^(x&y)^(y&z)^(x&y&z))
Latitudg:&o7>o4135q, longiuudu: u=/w}581   y^z^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
n{..|}go.&.?..673.q<:lon..uutu....?w.587   ~(x^(x&y)^(x&z))
. rh...EmH!tH&.p]e2maS.%LD B.'\ .I@.(qv`   x^(x&y&z)
6:.....M.H.|...v].2}{S.%.. B.'....P..qvf   ~(y^z^(x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z))
Tavise$Eoh%th.0q.e2maS.enddbeg| .yh?8q~a   x^z^(x&z)^(y&z)
v{..{m'M.h.|..2w..2}{S.e..dbug....x?.q~g   (x&~z)|~y
. rh..De}H)vX&.p]u3ma_O/MM0W.'^ 5IF.)uvp   (x&~y)|(y&~z)
>:....Gm.H.~...v].3}{_O/..0W.'..?.V..uvv   (x&~y)|~z
\aviwude.h-vx.4q.u3ma_ooomtweg~ 5yn?9u~q   (x|y|z)&(~y|~z)
~{...}gm.h.~..6w..3}{_oo..twug..?.~?.u~w   ~(y&z)
. rh...GmNcuNg.p]ermas.%LD!B.7\ UMAYlqv`   x^(y&z)
6:.....O.N.}...v].r}{s.%..!B.7.._.QY.qvf   ~(y^z^(x&y)^(x&z)^(x&y&z))
Tavise$Gonguno0q.ermas.endebew| U}i.|q~a   x^z^(x&z)^(x&y&z)
v{..{m'O.n.}..2w..r}{s.e..ebuw.._.y..q~g   ~(y^(x&y)^(y&z))
. rh..Dg}Nkw^g.p]usma.O/MM1W.7^ uMGYmuvp   x^y^(x&y)^(x&y&z)
>:....Go.N.....v].s}{.O/..1W.7....WY.uvv   ~(z^(x&z)^(y&z))
\aviwudg.now~o4q.usma.ooomuwew~ u}o.}u~q   (~x|~y|~z)&(x|y|z)
~{...}go.n....6w..s}{.oo..uwuw.......u~w   ~(x&y&z)
........................................   x&y&z
........................................   (x&y&z)|(~x&~y&~z)
............!...........2 .... ..0......   z^(x&z)^(y&z)
........................................   (x&y&z)|(~x&~y)
........................................   y^(x&y)^(y&z)
........................................   (x&y&z)|(~x&~z)
............1...........3)...."..0......   y^z^(x&y)^(x&z)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~(x^(y&z))
..........B..A......................D...   y&z
........................................   (~x&~y&~z)|(y&z)
..........F.'I..........2 .... ..4..T...   (~x|y)&z
........................................   (~x&~y)|(y&z)
..........J..A......................E...   (~x|z)&y
........................................   (y&z)^(~x&~z)
..........N.7I..........3)...."..4..U...   (~x&y)|(~x&z)|(y&z)
........................................   ~x|(y&z)
........E...A....@............D..@......   x^(x&y)^(x&z)
........................................   (x&y&z)|(~y&~z)
........G...a....@......:$....d..p......   x^z^(x&y)^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~(y^(x&z))
........U...Q....P............F..@......   x^y^(x&z)^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~(z^(x&y))
........W...q....P......;-....f..p......   x^y^z
........................................   ~((x&y)^(x&z)^(y&z)^(x&y&z))
........E.B.GA...@............D..D..D...   (x&~y&~z)|(y&z)
........................................   ~(y^z)
........G.F.gI...@......:$....d..t..T...   x^z^(x&y)
........................................   (~x|y|~z)&(~y|z)
........U.J.WA...P............F..D..E...   x^y^(x&z)
........................................   (~x|~y|z)&(y|~z)
........W.N.wI...P......;-....f..t..U...   x^y^z^(y&z)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~((x&y)^(x&z))
........................................   x&z
........................................   (x&z)|(~x&~y&~z)
............!...........2 ....(..8......   (x|~y)&z
........................................   (x&z)|(~x&~y)
........................................   (x&z)|(~x&y&~z)
........................................   ~(x^z)
............1...........3)....*..8......   y^z^(x&y)
........................................   (~x|z)&(x|~y|~z)
..........B..G......................L...   (x|y)&z
........................................   ~(x^y^z^(x&y))
..........F.'O..........2 ....(..<..\...   z
........................................   ~(x|y)|z
..........J..G......................M...   (x&z)|(~x&y)
........................................   (~x|z)&(x|y|~z)
..........N.7O..........3)....*..<..]...   (~x&y)|z
........................................   ~x|z
........E...A....A............L..H......   x&(~y|z)
........................................   (x&z)^(~y&~z)
........G...a....A......:$....l..x......   (x&~y)|(x&z)|(~y&z)
........................................   (x&z)|~y
........U...Q....Q............N..H......   x^y^(y&z)
........................................   (~x|~y|z)&(x|~z)
........W...q....Q......;-....n..x......   x^y^z^(x&z)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~((x&y)^(y&z))
........E.B.GG...A............L..L..L...   (x&~y)|(y&z)
........................................   (x|y|~z)&(~y|z)
........G.F.gO...A......:$....l..|..\...   (x&~y)|z
........................................   ~y|z
........U.J.WG...Q............N..L..M...   x^y^(x&y&z)
........................................   (~x|~y|z)&(x|y|~z)
........W.N.wO...Q......;-....n..|..]...   (x&~y)|(~x&y)|z
........................................   ~x|~y|z
..xx....(.!.. ...$......T@.....2.... ...   x&y
........................................   (x&y)|(~x&~y&~z)
..|y....*.%.)(...$......v`....02.1..0...   (x&y)|(~x&~y&z)
........................................   ~(x^y)
..xx....8.).. ...4......UI.....2....!...   (x|~z)&y
........................................   (x&y)|(~x&~z)
..|y....:.-.9(...4......wi....22.1..1...   y^z^(x&z)
........................................   (~x|y)&(x|~y|~z)
..xx....(.c..a...$......T@.....2....d...   (x|z)&y
........................................   ~(x^y^z^(x&z))
..|y....*.g./i...$......v`....02.5..t...   (x&y)|(~x&z)
........................................   (~x|y)&(x|~y|z)
..xx....8.k..a...4......UI.....2....e...   y
........................................   ~(x|z)|y
..|y....:.o.?i...4......wi....22.5..u...   (~x&z)|y
........................................   ~x|y
..zx....m.!.I ...d......\D....T2.A.. ...   x&(y|~z)
........................................   (x&y)|(~y&~z)
..~y....o.%.i(...d......~d....t2.q..0...   x^z^(y&z)
........................................   (~x|y|~z)&(x|~y)
..zx....}.).Y ...t......]M....V2.A..!...   (x&y)|(x&~z)|(y&~z)
........................................   (x&y)|~z
..~y......-.y(...t.......m....v2.q..1...   x^y^z^(x&y)^(x&y&z)
........................................   ~((x&z)^(y&z))
..zx....m.c.Oa...d......\D....T2.E..d...   x^(x&z)^(y&z)
........................................   (x|~y|z)&(y|~z)
..~y....o.g.oi...d......~d....t2.u..t...   x^z^(x&y&z)
........................................   (~x|y|~z)&(x|~y|z)
..zx....}.k._a...t......]M....V2.E..e...   (x&~z)|y
........................................   y|~z
..~y......o..i...t.......m....v2.u..u...   (x&~z)|(~x&z)|y
........................................   ~x|y|~z
..xx....(.!..&...%......T@.....2....(...   x&(y|z)
........................................   ~(x^y^z^(y&z))
..|y....*.%.)....%......v`....82.9..8...   (x&y)|(~y&z)
........................................   (~x|y|z)&(x|~y)
..xx....8.)..&...5......UI.....2....)...   y^(x&z)^(y&z)
........................................   (~x|y|z)&(x|~z)
..|y....:.-.9....5......wi....:2.9..9...   y^z^(x&y&z)
........................................   (~x|y|z)&(x|~y|~z)
..xx....(.c..g...%......T@.....2....l...   (x&y)|(x&z)|(y&z)
........................................   ~(x^y^z^(x&y&z))
..|y....*.g./o...%......v`....82.=..|...   (x&y)|z
........................................   (x&y)|(~x&~y)|z
..xx....8.k..g...5......UI.....2....m...   (x&z)|y
........................................   (x&z)|(~x&~z)|y
..|y....:.o.?o...5......wi....:2.=..}...   y|z
........................................   ~x|y|z
..zx....m.!.I&...e......\D....\2.I..(...   x
........................................   x|~(y|z)
..~y....o.%.i....e......~d....|2.y..8...   x|(~y&z)
........................................   x|~y
..zx....}.).Y&...u......]M....^2.I..)...   x|(y&~z)
........................................   x|~z
..~y......-.y....u.......m....~2.y..9...   x|(y&~z)|(~y&z)
........................................   x|~y|~z
..zx....m.c.Og...e......\D....\2.M..l...   x|(y&z)
........................................   x|(y&z)|(~y&~z)
..~y....o.g.oo...e......~d....|2.}..|...   x|z
........................................   x|~y|z
..zx....}.k._g...u......]M....^2.M..m...   x|y
........................................   x|y|~z
..~y......o..o...u.......m....~2.}..}...   x|y|z
```

Quickly scanning through them, we see the lines:

> `Pavica Bongani Andreas Andebert Quintana`

and

> `Latitude: -68.41351, Longitude: 59.79581`

The latter of which is [a point in Antarctica](https://www.google.com/maps/place/68%C2%B024'48.6%22S+59%C2%B047'44.9%22E/@-59.9464482,22.8105192,9534314m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-68.41351!4d59.79581)

Comment: Another method which I did not even know existed!